Opentelemetry collector contrib for azure monitor in aks as standalone not working
I am trying to have a standalone deployment of otel collector contrib for exporting logs to azure monitor by deploying in aks. I try to push the logs but none of the logs are reaching the collector. Any working yaml configuration will be helpful
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: otel-collector
 namespace: otelcollector
 labels:
   app: otelcollector
   component: otel-collector
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: otelcollector
     component: otel-collector
 minReadySeconds: 5
 replicas: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     namespace: otelcollector
     labels:
       app: otelcollector
       component: otel-collector
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: otel-collector
         command:
        #   # - '/otelcol'
          - '--config=/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml'
         image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
         resources:
           limits:
             cpu: '1'
             memory: 2Gi
           requests:
             cpu: 200m
             memory: 400Mi
         ports:
          #  - containerPort: 4317   #otlp grpc
           - containerPort: 4318   # otlp http
           - containerPort: 55679  # zpages
           - containerPort: 13133  # health check
         volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml
             name: data
             subPath: config.yaml
             readOnly: true
     volumes:
       - name: data
         configMap:
          name: otel-collector-config


@SureshChikkam I will be implementing your suggestions this week.

@SureshChikkam it worked thanks. But one problem was i need to explicitly add these endpoints. http://customotel.collector.com:4318/v1/metrics , http://customotel.collector.com:4318/v1/traces, http://customotel.collector.com:4318/v1/logs
its not pushing the logs if i just mention http://customotel.collector.com:4318


I try to push the logs but none of the logs are reaching the collector.

otel-collector-config.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: otel-collector-config
  namespace: otelcollector
data:
  config.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:
    
    processors:
      batch:
    
    exporters:
      azuremonitor:
        instrumentation_key: "<YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY>"
    
    service:
      pipelines:
        logs:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [azuremonitor]


Below is the Deployment YAML that references the ConfigMap. This configuration mounts the config.yaml from the ConfigMap and check that the Collector is started with the appropriate configuration.

otel-collector-deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
  namespace: otelcollector
  labels:
    app: otelcollector
    component: otel-collector
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: otelcollector
      component: otel-collector
  minReadySeconds: 5
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: otelcollector
      labels:
        app: otelcollector
        component: otel-collector
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: otel-collector
          image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest
          args:
            - "--config=/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 400Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4317 # OTLP gRPC
            - containerPort: 4318 # OTLP HTTP
            - containerPort: 55679 # zPages
            - containerPort: 13133 # health check
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml
              name: config
              subPath: config.yaml
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: otel-collector-config

After deployment, verify that the OpenTelemetry Collector is running and exporting logs.

Logs from OpenTelemetry Collector Pod:
2024-05-20T08:00:00.000Z    info    service/collector.go:266    Starting otelcontribcol...    {"Version": "0.34.0", "GitHash": "abcd1234"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.001Z    info    service/collector.go:273    Loading configuration...
2024-05-20T08:00:00.002Z    info    service/collector.go:286    Applying configuration...
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    builder/exporters_builder.go:255    Exporter was built.    {"kind": "exporter", "name": "azuremonitor"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    builder/pipelines_builder.go:212    Pipeline was built.    {"name": "logs", "input_type": "logs"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    builder/receivers_builder.go:231    Receiver was built.    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "datatype": "logs"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    service/service.go:143    Starting extensions...
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    service/service.go:188    Starting exporters...
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    builder/exporters_builder.go:81    Exporter started.    {"kind": "exporter", "name": "azuremonitor"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    service/service.go:193    Starting processors...
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    builder/pipelines_builder.go:55    Pipeline is starting...    {"name": "logs", "input_type": "logs"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    builder/pipelines_builder.go:65    Pipeline is started.    {"name": "logs", "input_type": "logs"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.003Z    info    service/service.go:198    Starting receivers...
2024-05-20T08:00:00.004Z    info    builder/receivers_builder.go:70    Receiver started.    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "datatype": "logs"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.004Z    info    healthcheck/handler.go:128    Health Check server started    {"endpoint": "0.0.0.0:13133", "status": "success"}
2024-05-20T08:00:00.004Z    info    service/service.go:206    OpenTelemetry Collector Contrib started.
2024-05-20T08:00:10.000Z    info    otlpreceiver/otlp.go:79    Received a new request.    {"protocol": "grpc"}
2024-05-20T08:00:10.001Z    info    batchprocessor/batch_processor.go:139    Batch processor received logs.    {"count": 50}
2024-05-20T08:00:10.002Z    info    azuremonitorexporter/azure_monitor.go:57    Successfully sent logs to Azure Monitor.    {"count": 50}
2024-05-20T08:00:20.000Z    info    otlpreceiver/otlp.go:79    Received a new request.    {"protocol": "grpc"}
2024-05-20T08:00:20.001Z    info    batchprocessor/batch_processor.go:139    Batch processor received logs.    {"count": 100}
2024-05-20T08:00:20.002Z    info    azuremonitorexporter/azure_monitor.go:57    Successfully sent logs to Azure Monitor.    {"count": 100}

